# A question about merged Poisson process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

**Question here:**

Iwana Passe is taking a multiple-choice exam. You may assume that the number of questions is infinite. **Simultaneously, but independently,** her conscious and subconscious faculties are generating answers for her, each in a Poisson manner. (Her conscious andsubconscious are always working on *different* questions.) Conscious responses are generated at the rate $λ_c$ responses per minute. Subconscious responses are generated at the rate $λ_s$ responses per minute. Assume $λ_c \neq λ_s$. Each conscious response is an independent Bernoulli trial with probability $p_c$ of being
 correct. Similarly, each subconscious response is an independent Bernoulli trial with probability $p_s$ of being correct. Iwana responds only once to each question, and you can assume that her time for recording these conscious and subconscious responses is negligible.

**All my solutions are based on the fact that conscious and subconscious responses form the merged Poisson process.**

(a)
If we pick an interval of T minutes, what is the probability that in that interval Iwana will make exactly $r$ conscious responses and $s$ subconscious responses?

*My solution*: Because this is the merged Poisson process, so the probability when conscious happens    is $\frac{\lambda_c}{\lambda_c+\lambda_s} $ , similar for the subconscious. Thus the probability is $$ \binom{r+s}{r} \frac{(\lambda_c)^r(\lambda_s)^s}{(\lambda_c+\lambda_s)^{s+r}} $$

*But the given answer is*:

Since the conscious and subconscious responses are generated independently,

**P**($r$ conscious responses and s subconscious responses in interval $T$)

= **P**($r$ conscious responses in $T$)**P**($s$ unconscious responses in $T$) = $$ \frac{(\lambda_cT)^re^{-\lambda_cT}}{r!}\cdot \frac{(\lambda_sT)^se^{-\lambda_sT}}{s!}$$

I think that the total events are given, the interval T is not in the business.

Appreciate  if you help! Thanks!

A similar question:
[image: Aha]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote is $\textsf{Pr}(R=r\land S=s\mid R+S=r+s)$. What they wrote (and what the question asked for) is $\textsf{Pr}(R=r\land S=s)$. The latter depends on the interval, the former doesn't.

Comment: *If we pick an interval of T minutes*  I think it is the given condition. What's the wrong?

Comment: @standerQiu: I wouldn't consider that as a condition but as the specification of the random variables we're looking at. I guess you could interpret "pick" probabilistically in that sentence and consider it as a condition, but I don't see how that would change things -- you'd then just add that condition in both cases -- the main point would be the same, that you considered $R+S$ as given and they didn't.

Comment: They are different -- the given condition would not involve with time. How could I get out of the trap? It seems to be a language game..

Comment: @standerQiu: I'm afraid we seem to be talking past each other. Perhaps you could explain your question to a native English speaker and have them translate it?

Comment: Er... I don't know about any native speaker.. I am sorry, is that my English too awkward..? But I think I grasp your idea.. What I mean different is that you say **he main point would be the same, that you considered R+SR+S as given and they didn't.** .  I don't agree with you because if I do not treat *If we pick an interval of T minutes* as a condition, the time **T** would be involved

Comment: @standerQiu: Whether you think of $T$ as a condition or a part of the problem specification is just a conceptual difference; it doesn't change the fact that $T$ is involved. Their expression (involving $T$) is correct; it would still be correct if you wrote it as "$P (\text{$r$ conscious responses and $s$ subconscious responses}\mid\text{interval $T$ was picked})$" instead of "$P (\text{$r$ conscious responses and $s$ subconscious responses in interval $T$})$".

Comment: I add a similar question and given answer above. Could you see that? Because of that question, I am confused when to involve time..

Comment: Before that question, I also think what you think. lol..

Comment: @standerQiu: The two parts of that question correspond directly to the two calculations we've been talking about. In part (a), the total number of jobs is not given, and the answer will depend on the time interval (in this case given as three minutes). In part (b), the total number of jobs is given; then the time interval no longer matters and the probability (conditioned on the total number of jobs) depends only on the relative probabilities of the types of jobs.

Comment: @standerQiu: I think it might be a good exercise for you to derive that from first principles, i.e. not use the fact that we know the conditional probability won't depend on the time interval, but calculate it using the time-dependent unconditional probabilities and show that the time interval drops out when you conditionalise on the sum.

Comment: Oh! Thank you for you last comment!!!!!  Can I ask the last question? I used to think that *exactly r conscious responses and s subconscious responses* was the total number of jobs *r +s* given... But it seems not?

Comment: @standerQiu: I'm not sure I understand that question. If you're *given* that there are exactly $r$ conscious responses and $s$ subconscious responses, then you're also given the sum $r+s$ -- but that's not what's happening here -- the sum $r+s$ is given, and the question asks for the probability of that sum arising from exactly $r$ conscious responses and $s$ subconscious responses (as opposed to, say, exactly $r+1$ conscious responses and $s-1$ subconscious responses, which would have the same sum).

Comment: Oh!! I think that the *main idea* of the question is the probability **during a time interval** instead of **fixed exact job events**!!!! That's what you express. Thank you very much!!!!!!!!!!!!!! You are so nice and patient!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!